# Efficient cummulative sum in Python

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I have a vector `a` of known size N, so that `np.sum(a)` is 1, and `np.all(a>=0)` is true. I want to determine the minimum number of entries that sum a threshold `t`. For instance, I would do something like:

```
idx = np.argsort(a)
asorted = a[idx][::-1]
sum_ = 0
number = 0
while sum_ < t:
    number += 1
    sum_ = np.sum(asorted[:number])
```

as soon as `sum_` is greater than `t`, the program stops, and the variable `number` tells me the minimum number of entries that sum that threshold.

I am looking for the most efficient way of getting this number, as I have to perform this operation millions of times.

Comment: Why do you do `sum_ = np.sum(a[:number])` instead of `sum_ += a[number - 1]`?

Comment: How large is N?

Comment: Do you have to answer the millions of operations one at a time, or can you do them all together (i.e., you get a list of thresholds and return a list of results)?

Comment: @HeapOverflow one at a time, N can be of the order of 4^8- 4^12, the threshold is actually the same, but I have to first load the vectors `a`, and I cannot load them all because of memory issues.

Comment: what are `idx` and `asorted` used for in your code?

Comment: Perhaps `sum_ = np.sum(a[:number])` is meant to be `sum_ = np.sum(asorted[:number])`?

Comment: Still unclear why you're calling `np.sum` over and over again. Is it a precision issue? Speaking of which, can you tell us more about the numbers? I mean, in general there's a good chance they *don't* add up to 1. For example, `np.sum([0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1])` isn't `1` but `0.9999999999999999`.

Comment: It's an error on my part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(**EDITED**)

(**EDIT2**: added a more specialized JIT-ed version to address issues when using `np.sort()` with `numba`.)

(**EDIT3**: included timing for the recursive approach with median pivoting from [@hilberts_drinking_problem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60661627/5218354))

I am not 100% what you are after, because the first two lines of your code seems to be doing nothing, but after @hilberts_drinking_problem I have edited my answer, I assume that you have a typo and:

```
sum_ = np.sum(arr[:i])
```

should be:

```
sum_ = np.sum(asorted[:i])
```

---

Then, your solution can be written as a function like:

```
import numpy as np


def min_sum_threshold_orig(arr, threshold=0.5):
    idx = np.argsort(arr)
    arr_sorted = arr[idx][::-1]
    sum_ = 0
    i = 0
    while sum_ < threshold:
        i += 1
        sum_ = np.sum(arr_sorted[:i])
    return i
```

However:

1. Instead of `np.argsort()` and indexing you could use `np.sort()` directly
2. there is no need to compute the entire sum at each iteration, but you could instead use the sum from the previous iteration
3. Using a while loop is risky because if `threshold` is sufficiently high (`> 1.0` with your assumption) then the loop will never end

Addressing these points one gets to:

```
def min_sum_threshold(arr, threshold=0.5):
    arr = np.sort(arr)[::-1]
    sum_ = 0
    for i in range(arr.size):
        sum_ += arr[i]
        if sum_ >= threshold:
            break
    return i + 1
```

In the above, the explicit looping becomes the bottleneck. A good way of addressing it, is to use `numba`:

```
import numba as nb


min_sum_threshold_nbn = nb.jit(min_sum_threshold)
min_sum_threshold_nbn.__name__ = 'min_sum_threshold_nbn'
```

But this may not be the most efficient approach as `numba` is relatively slow when new arrays are being created.
A possibly faster approach is to use `arr.sort()` instead of `np.sort()` because that is in-place, thus avoiding the creation of a new array:

```
@nb.jit
def min_sum_thres_nb_inplace(arr, threshold=0.5):
    arr.sort()
    sum_ = 0
    for i in range(arr.size - 1, -1, -1):
        sum_ += arr[i]
        if sum_ >= threshold:
            break
    return arr.size - i
```

Alternatively, one could JIT only the portion of code after the sorting:

```
@nb.jit
def _min_sum_thres_nb(arr, threshold=0.5):
    sum_ = 0.0
    for i in range(arr.size):
        sum_ += arr[i]
        if sum_ >= threshold:
            break
    return i + 1


def min_sum_thres_nb(arr, threshold=0.5):
    return _min_sum_thres_nb(np.sort(arr)[::-1], threshold)
```

The difference between the two will be minimal for larger inputs. For smaller one, `min_sum_thres_nb()` will be dominated by the comparatively slow extra function call.
Because of the pitfails in benchmarking functions which modify their input, `min_sum_thres_nb_inplace()` is omitted from benchmarks, with the understanding that for very small inputs is as fast as `min_sum_thres_nbn()` and for larger ones it has essentially the same performances as `min_sum_thres_nb()`.

---

Alternatively one could use a vectorized approaches like in [@yatu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60661122/5218354):

```
def min_sum_threshold_np_sum(arr, threshold=0.5):
    return np.sum(np.cumsum(np.sort(arr)[::-1]) < threshold) + 1
```

or, better, use `np.searchsorted()` which avoids creating an unnecessary temporary array with the comparison:

```
def min_sum_threshold_np_ss(arr, threshold=0.5):
    return np.searchsorted(np.cumsum(np.sort(arr)[::-1]), threshold) + 1
```

or, assuming that sorting the entire array is unnecessarily expensive:

```
def min_sum_threshold_np_part(arr, threshold=0.5):
    n = arr.size
    m = np.int(size * threshold) + 1
    part_arr = np.partition(arr, n - m)[n - m:]
    return np.searchsorted(np.cumsum(np.sort(arr)[::-1]), threshold) + 1
```

An even more sophisticated approach using recursion and median pivoting is:

```
def min_sum_thres_rec(arr, threshold=0.5, cutoff=64):
    n = arr.size
    if n <= cutoff:
        return np.searchsorted(np.cumsum(np.sort(arr)[::-1]), threshold) + 1
    else:
        m = n // 2
        partitioned = np.partition(arr, m)
        low = partitioned[:m]
        high = partitioned[m:]
        sum_high = np.sum(high)
        if sum_high >= threshold:
            return min_sum_thres_rec(high, threshold)
        else:
            return min_sum_thres_rec(low, threshold - sum_high) + high.size
```

(the last three are adapted from [@hilberts_drinking_problem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60661627/5218354))

---

Benchmarking these with the input generated from this:

```
def gen_input(n, a=0, b=10000):
    arr = np.random.randint(a, b, n)
    arr = arr / np.sum(arr)
    return arr
```

gives the following:

[image: bm_full]
[image: bm_zoom]

These indicate that for small enough inputs, the `numba` approach is the fastest, but as soon as the input exceeds ~600 elements for the naive approach or ~900 for the *optimized* one, the NumPy approaches which uses `np.partition()`, while being less memory efficient, are faster.

Eventually, beyond ~4000 elements, the `min_sum_thres_rec()` gets faster than all other proposed methods.
It may be possible to write a faster numba-based implementation of this method.

Note that the *optimized* `numba` approach is strictly faster than the naive NumPy approaches that were tested.

Comment: I believe the OP wants to find _minimum_ number of elements summing to `t`. If `a` is unsorted, your `find_cumsum_threshold` function is not guaranteed to give correct output. I am guessing that there was a typo in the question, and `sum_ = np.sum(a[:number])` is meant to be `sum_ = np.sum(asorted[:number])`.

Comment: I like the use of numba here. I will check if this is faster than the answer by @hilberts_drinking_problem

Comment: You never use `part_arr`. And something curious: In `min_sum_threshold`, when I `return` right after the first line (the sorting), the non-Numba version becomes significantly *faster* than the Numba version, and the Numba version remains around the same time (so apparently the sorting takes almost all the time and the loop takes almost none). If I do the sorting before calling those two functions, the Numba version is about 800 times faster than the non-Numba version.

Comment: @norok2 I added a linear time algorithm, if you feel like updating the benchmarks in the future ;)

Comment: @HeapOverflow I have included a version which addresses the problem with `np.sort()`, which is essentially that numba gets slower with allocation of new memory, hence either in-place operations must be used from NumPy OR the memory allocation is done outside numba. @hilbert_drinking_problem cool! I have already updated it.

Answer (score 3):

It just occurred to me that there is a recursive linear time algorithm for this based on median pivoting:

```
def min_sum_rec(arr, t=0.5):
  n = arr.size
  # default to sorting for small arrays
  if n <= 100:
    return np.searchsorted(np.sort(arr)[::-1].cumsum(), t) + 1
  partitioned = np.partition(arr, n//2)
  low = partitioned[:n//2]
  high = partitioned[n//2:]
  sum_high = high.sum()
  if sum_high >= t:
    return min_sum_rec(high, t)
  else:
    return min_sum_rec(low, t - sum_high) + high.size
```

Here is comparison to my previous O(n log(n)) solution, in seconds:

```
N           min_sum_rec  num_to_t
10            0.000041  0.000038
100           0.000025  0.000028
1000          0.000086  0.000042
10000         0.000321  0.000310
100000        0.002547  0.003259
1000000       0.028826  0.039854
10000000      0.247731  0.431744
100000000     2.371766  4.800107
```

---

Previous solution, which can be faster for smaller-sized arrays:

In addition to using `cumsum`, note that the average element of the array has size `1/N`. Hence, it takes at most `t*N` elements to add up to `t`. For small `t`, this provides an optimization opportunity where we make an `O(N)` call to `np.partition`, followed by sorting of `t*N` largest elements:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

a = np.random.rand(10**6)
a /= a.sum()
t = 1e-3


def num_to_t_sort(a, t):
  c = np.sort(a)[::-1].cumsum()
  return np.searchsorted(c, t) + 1


def num_to_t(a, t):
  n = len(a)
  m = np.int(n * t) + 1
  b = np.partition(a, n-m)[n-m:]
  b[::-1].sort()
  c = b.cumsum()
  return np.searchsorted(c, t) + 1


assert num_to_t(a, t) == num_to_t_sort(a, t)
%timeit num_to_t(a, t)      # 100 loops, best of 3: 11.8 ms per loop
%timeit num_to_t_sort(a, t) # 10 loops, best of 3: 107 ms per loop
```

A similar optimization applies if `t` tends to be close to `1`. If you are repeating operations for the same array and different t, you are probably better of storing `c = np.sort(a)[::-1].cumsum()` and calling `np.searchsorted` for each `t`.

Also, I am assuming that every element is strictly positive. Otherwise, one needs to consider two separate cases depending on whether `t` occurs in `c`.

Comment: Note that `np.searchsorted(c, t, side='right')` might occasionally give a different result compared to OP code. `np.searchsorted(c, t) + 1` (so `side='left'`) should be used instead.

Comment: Good point, I noticed that. I originally convinced myself that there was an edge case against `side='left'` as well, but it seems that I was imagining things.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the length of the arrays, maybe sort, and then you could use a [cumulative sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html)? It would at least be faster than that while loop.

```
>>> a = np.array(range(10)[::-1])
>>> a
array([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
>>> b = np.cumsum(a)
>>> b
array([ 9, 17, 24, 30, 35, 39, 42, 44, 45, 45])
```

Then just use `argmax`, say you wanted the index where it passed 40:

```
>>> np.argmax(b > 40)
6
```

Comment: yes, you need to flip that sorted array before the cumsum!

Comment: Oops, right. Thanks! Edited to flip the array. And upped the value to make it actually do something.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a NumPy based approach:

```
(np.cumsum(np.sort(a)[::-1]) < t).sum() + 1
```

---

For instance:

```
a = np.array([1,2,8,5,13,9])

(np.cumsum(np.sort(a)[::-1]) < 25).sum() + 1
# 3
```

Where:

```
np.sort(a)[::-1]
# array([13,  9,  8,  5,  2,  1])
```

And:

```
np.cumsum(np.sort(a)[::-1])
# array([13, 22, 30, 35, 37, 38])
```